# Regex doesn't matches

Tags: java, regex, text-processing

I've a trouble with regexp in such situation:
I need to extract (and replace) all dots from such construction:

```
any_symbols->white_space->x.(or xx. or Xx. or xX. or xy. or yy. etc.)->white_space->any_symbol_not_upper_case_and_not_a_digit
```

for example

```
1990 x. abcd  -  extract dot

ffff xx.abcd  -  extract dot

1990 x. Abcdef    -  do not extract

abcd x. Abcd      -  do not extract

abcd x. 1990      -  do not extract
```

So I've constructed such regexp:

```
(?<=\s[XxYy]{1,2})\.(?>=\s+?[^\p{javaUpperCase}\d])
```

But it doesn't matches. So what's wrong?

Thanks

**P.S.**

After

```
String skipPtrn="(?<=\\s[РрГг]{1,2})\\.(?>=\\s+?[^\\p{javaUpperCase}\\d])";
originalText=originalText.replaceAll(skipPtrn, " ");
```

I'm still finding in text:

> 1673 р. з'явився
>
> У 1623 р. через
>
> у 1925 р. ("Вiсник

etc.

Comment: According to your description, the white spaces are not optional. According to your samples, they are. What is correct?

Comment: Is your regex not matching any of your samples or does it match all?

Comment: Extracting dot, when previous symbols are: white_space and [XxYy]{1,2}, and when following after dot symbols, are: (white_spaces(s) and non upper_case_symbols and non_digits)

Comment: I've supplemented text of main question (P.S.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `>` sign from the look ahead group: `(?<=\s[XxYy]{1,2})\.(?=\s+?[^\p{javaUpperCase}\d])`. You can do `(?>x)` (atomic group) or `(?=x)` (zero-width positive lookahead) but not `(?>=x)`.

Also note that your second example doesn't match your description and would not be matched with the above regex.

Answer (score 1):

Look ahead is not necessary at all:

```
$ perl -wne 's/^(\w+\s+[XxYy]{1,2})\.(\s*[^A-Z\d]+)$/$1$2/;print' <data.txt 
1990 x abcd
ffff xxabcd
1990 x. Abcdef
abcd x. Abcd
abcd x. 1990
```

Comment: +1 for pointing that out. People are somehow obsessed to complicate things with look ahead/behind, no matter if it's needed.